# Stored Procedure - flowchart layout

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures, db2, flowchart

I have a working stored procedure code that calls a table from the SAMPLE database.
But my problem now is I am confused on how do i make it into a flowchart as the conditions are within the SELECT statement itself.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TAXDUE ()

    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
    LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN

    DECLARE display CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR     
        SELECT EMPNO, LASTNAME, SALARY,
                   CASE 
                     WHEN SALARY < 15001 THEN SALARY 
                     WHEN SALARY BETWEEN 15001 AND 22000 THEN SALARY * 0.05
                     WHEN SALARY BETWEEN 20001 AND 32000 THEN (SALARY * 0.07) + 125
                     WHEN SALARY BETWEEN 32001 AND 45000 THEN (SALARY * 0.10) + 200
                     ELSE SALARY
                   END AS "TAX DUE"          
        FROM EMPLOYEE 
        WHERE WORKDEPT IN ('A00', 'B01', 'C01');

    OPEN display;

END
```

How do i layout this into a flowchart? I can visualize it never tried making a flowchart out of a SELECT statement that has conditions in it.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... things like stored procedures are **highly vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: i just want to know how do i make a flowchart out of this.
i am using IBM DB2 v9.5 and Data Studio v3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is a declarative language.

You specify **what** you want not **how** to get it. As such you cannot really flow chart a piece of SQL as the "flow" is all about how something is acheived.

You can run an "explain" to see **how** the RDBMS retrieved the data on this database at this time, but RDBMSes are fickle and change their access paths frequently.

Comment: thanks for the info. i just improvised my own flowchart that explains my code.